# Sort List of Vector3's by specific values

Tags: c#, sorting, vector, find, max

I have a list of Vector 3's and what I want to do is find the Vector3 with the highest X value, if there are multiple Vector3's with the highest X I want to have the Vector 3 with the lowest Y and highest X. I want the method to return the Z of that Vector3. What is the best way to do this?

Sorry, I am very new to coding, I hope I've explained my problem well enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: something like this `vector.OrderBy(v => v.x).ToArray<Vector3>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with linq:

```
if (vectors.Count == 0)
{
     //Some appropriate action
}
else
{
    return vectors.OrderyBy(v => v.X)
                  .ThenByDescending(v => v.Y)
                  .Last()
                  .Z
}
```

Do note that your problem is under specified:

- What happens if the list is empty?
- What happens if more than one vector with maximum `X` and minimum `Y` exist?

Comment: In my case it is impossible for the list to be empty because I have defined it manually. Also it is impossible (in my case) that there are two identical y values.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good way to do it:

```
Vector3[] arr; 
 Vector3 res = arr[0]; 

 for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
     if (arr[i].x > res.x || (arr[i].x == res.x && arr[i].y < res.y)){
         res = arr[i];
     }
 } 
 return res.z;
```